# WMS request response in GeoJSON

Tags: geoserver, geojson, wms, getfeatureinfo

I am trying to fetch data from geoserver WMS layer in geojson.
When previewing layer everything works fine:

```
http://79.101.20.137:8080/geoserver/eig/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=eig%3Atp&bbox=12.612376313105207%2C32.874999390114596%2C35.97501363287868%2C47.634998931418615&width=768&height=485&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers
```

I tried to adjust above link with using [this tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/geojson.html) to get json response:

```
http://79.101.20.137:8080/geoserver/eig/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=application/json&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=eig:t2m&LAYERS=eig:t2m&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=4.2254877427993645,50.750177078705356,4.4957029774594135,50.921063532317916
```

but I got empty json response:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":0,"timeStamp":"2023-01-15T20:00:24.592Z","crs":null}
```

I tried with testing with different layers, but no luck so far. Layers are created from raster images and the have time dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct URL to get JSON is

```
http://79.101.20.137:8080/geoserver/eig/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=eig:tp&STYLES=&LAYERS=eig:tp&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=13.58940124511719,44.68002319335938,13.728103637695314,44.81872558593751
```

It returns

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":0.3075000047683716}}],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2023-01-15T20:33:29.629Z","crs":null}
```

I used the browser network console, clicked, and just changed the `INFO_FORMAT` to `application/json`. All else I copied verbatim from the request the demo GUI sent.

When you sent your request you used `FORMAT=application/json`, which tries to request the WMS image in `application/json`. This obviously does not work, although I don't see why a GetFeatureInfo request needs the format parameter anyways, because it's not returning an image...

Comment: It needs it because dumb clients can just add `Info_Format` and `I` and `J` to the whole request with out any need to parse it and modify it

Comment: It needs it because the GetFeatureInfo request is stateless.  The server doesn't know what map was being looked at when the client clicks on a location.  So the info request has to include all the information to create the map, plus extra parameters to specify the response for the information